# increment field by some number without updating timestamps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have to update `reputation` attribute of `User` model after he create a `Post`. 
Here is what I have tried so far:

Simple solution is:

```
User.find(id).increment!(reputation: 10)
```

But, this also, updates the `updated_at` field.

I looked up for a way to update counter without updating timestamps, and found this:

```
User.increment_counter(:reputation, id)
```

But this method increments `reputation` by 1.

I also, found out that `update_column` method doesn't updates timestamps.
But, I can't seem to use it as one-liner query.

As, I have to update the reputation of User after he creates a post. So, in my `Post` model,

```
after_create_commit { self.user.update_column(reputation: (self.user.reputation + 10))}
```

This query is calling `self.user` (to get associated user of current post) 2 times, how can I avoid this.

OR

Is there any other method to increment without updating timestamps.

Thanks

**Update:**

Found one solution, `update_counters` method (added in the answers below).

If someone knows about any other method, or can help me with how can I user update_column without calling `self.user` two times, please help me out. 
Thanks

Comment: Why would you _not_ want to update the `updated_at` field when changing the user's attributes in the first place?

Comment: Hi, because I need updated_at field for some other purpose in my Admin Dashboard, that is another story :)

Comment: You might consider using a custom field for that purpose instead. It's usually easier to follow the conventions instead of using low-level methods in order to circumvent them ;-)

Comment: right! l'll definitely follow conventions in my new projects but as this project is already up and running so I am hoping to get a work around without fixing my noob mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, found the solution. So, apparently, `update_counters` method is doing exactly what I needed.

```
User.update_counters :id,:reputation => 10
```

Thanks.

Link: [Rail Update Counters method](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/CounterCache/update_counters)